# Slow performance on view index

Tags: couchbase

I am trying to find the maximum value of an indexed value but getting very slow performance (over 15 minutes, bucket size >42M items, 100% resident). The index was created with

```
CREATE INDEX by_name ON sample(name) USING VIEW;
```

And queried by:

```
SELECT MAX(name) AS device FROM sample USE INDEX (by_name USING VIEW);
```

What can I do to increase performance?

Comment: Is there some specific reason you are using VIEW rather than GSI? This query should run very quickly on a GSI index. Generally speaking VIEW indexes are a deprecated technology at this point.

Comment: No specific reason, I am still trying to learn more about Couchbase.